# What is the best way to tell anonymous users apart?

Tags: sessions, cookies, chaos-tool-suite

My company wishes to split their website so that anonymous users are given slightly different sites based on a question when they first visit.

I intend to use a cookie to store the answer to the question between sessions, but I'm wondering what the best way is to use that answer once the user is browsing the site?  I intend to use page manager to handle the context but I'm still trying to determine where it should be stored:

- Cookies can be turned off by the user, or the IT department, much of our target audience have policies restricting or outright banning cookies
- Session variables seem to be the way to go, unless:
- Does the Global $user variable store different information for each anonymous visitor?

Are there downfalls in either of the latter two options?  Have I missed any options?

Comment: For those coming across this later: I decided to use subdomains to determine how content shows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Session variables seem to be the way to go

Don't forget that session variables rely on cookies

> Have I missed any options?

- The traditional solution would be to use the [ip address](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/ip_address/7) as a fallback if cookies are disabled.
- PHP does support an [alternative to cookie-based sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies) -- it can rewrite the URLs to include "?PHPSESSID=xyz". However, [securing this can be difficult](http://owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management).
- Another approach would be to use [html5 local storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) and do all the cusomizations on the client-side. This will work in all modern browsers regardless of cookie or firewall settings.

Comment: Session variables rely on cookies?  Bugger.

Comment: +1 html5 suggestion. FWIW, PHP does support an alternative to cookie-based sessions -- it can rewrite the URLs to include "?PHPSESSID=xyz" ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies ). However, securing this can be difficult ( https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management ).

Comment: Thanks @TimOtten I've incorporated your comments into my answer.